importing library in kaggle notebook
to install segmentation-models-pytorch I ran
!pip install -U segmentation-models-pytorch

and when importing
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp

I get error:

ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.
We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages
with the new resolver before it becomes the default.
bokeh 2.2.3 requires tornado>=5.1, but you'll have tornado 5.0.2 which
is incompatible. huggingface-hub 0.16.4 requires
typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3, but you'll have typing-extensions 3.7.4.1
which is incompatible. timm 0.9.2 requires torch>=1.7, but you'll have
torch 1.6.0 which is incompatible. WARNING: You are using pip version
20.2.4; however, version 24.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/conda/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade
pip' command.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
last)  in 
1 get_ipython().system('pip install -U segmentation-models-pytorch albumentations > /dev/null')
----> 2 import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/segmentation_models_pytorch/init.py
in 
1 from . import datasets
----> 2 from . import encoders
3 from . import decoders
4 from . import losses
5 from . import metrics
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/segmentation_models_pytorch/encoders/init.py
in 
----> 1 import timm
2 import functools
3 import torch.utils.model_zoo as model_zoo
4
5 from .resnet import resnet_encoders
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/timm/init.py in 
1 from .version import version
----> 2 from .layers import is_scriptable, is_exportable, set_scriptable, set_exportable
3 from .models import create_model, list_models, list_pretrained, is_model, list_modules, model_entrypoint, 
4     is_model_pretrained, get_pretrained_cfg, get_pretrained_cfg_value
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/timm/layers/init.py in

11 from .conv_bn_act import ConvNormAct, ConvNormActAa, ConvBnAct
12 from .create_act import create_act_layer, get_act_layer, get_act_fn
---> 13 from .create_attn import get_attn, create_attn
14 from .create_conv2d import create_conv2d
15 from .create_norm import get_norm_layer, create_norm_layer
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/timm/layers/create_attn.py in

9 from .cbam import CbamModule, LightCbamModule
10 from .eca import EcaModule, CecaModule
---> 11 from .gather_excite import GatherExcite
12 from .global_context import GlobalContext
13 from .halo_attn import HaloAttn
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/timm/layers/gather_excite.py in

20 from .create_conv2d import create_conv2d
21 from .helpers import make_divisible
---> 22 from .mlp import ConvMlp
23
24
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/timm/layers/mlp.py in 
98
99
--> 100 SwiGLUPacked = partial(GluMlp, act_layer=nn.SiLU, gate_last=False)
101
102
AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'SiLU'

how do I fix this?
I have tried updating the pytorch from 1.6.0 to latest, but in kaggle it seems not possible.

for those having the same issue, changing the kaggle notebook environment to 'always use latest environment' worked for me.
